# Modal close button doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I have a simple modal window that opens when a link is clicked and closes when the user clicks on the close button (represented in my fiddle as the red rectangle).

[Here is a link to my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsavage/zwN6R/30/)

This is the code :

```
// prize modal
$('.modal').on('click',function(){  
    if(!$('#prize-modal').hasClass('open')){
        $('#prize-modal').css('opacity',0.7);
        if($.browser.msie){
        $('#prize-modal').css('opacity','null').css('display','block').addClass('open');
        }else {
        $('#prize-modal').css('opacity',0).css('display','block').addClass('open').stop().animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
        }
    }
    return false;
}); 

// .close the class that you want to trigger the modal clossing

$('.close').on('click',function(){
    if($.browser.msie){
        $('.open').css('opacity','null').css('display','none').removeClass('open');
    }else {
        $('.open').stop().animate({opacity: 0}, 500,function()
        {
        $('.open').css('display','none').removeClass('open');
        });
    }
});
```

I cannot figure out why the "close" button is not working.

Comment: please post your code in the question.

Comment: Are you using jQuery 2 on purpose?

Comment: @j08691 - I am using Jquery 1.9 in my original file but for some reason in my fiddle when I tried to choose Jquery 1.9 (from the menu on the top left side of page) it would only select Jquery 2 from the dropdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$.browser.msie')`
```

> jQuery.browser() removed
>
> The jQuery.browser() method has been deprecated since jQuery 1.3 and
>   is removed in 1.9. If needed, it is available as part of the jQuery
>   [Migrate plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/). We recommend using feature detection with a library
>   such as Modernizr.

source: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zwN6R/31/

Comment: Thanks Eric for your response! I see it works in my fiddle but was wondering what you corrected to make it work? Thanks so much!

Comment: in version 1.9 jQuery.browser() was removed. For it to work you can use the [jQuery Migrate Plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/).

Comment: Hi Eric I've included the Jquery Migrate Plugin as suggested( included under where  I have jquery 1.9 in the head of my html) but for some reason it isnt working like it is in my fiddle. Here is a link http://www.joemsavage.com/misn_006/index.html

Comment: you have an error `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('.mySelectBoxClass').customSelect()')`

Comment: Thank you Eric for all your help! Appreciate it!